# MLRun Users and Roles configuration

Tags: mlops, mlrun

I'm struggling to find how to configure users and roles in my MLRun instance.

The documentation say that is possible to do this kind of control. Is this some feature of the premium version or I'm just being blind?

I can't even find something similar to a login screen on the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MLRun 1.2.1

- You can define user/identity and add roles only in MLRun managed version (not in CE - Community version)
- List of roles/policies [see](https://www.iguazio.com/docs/latest-release/users-and-security/security/#predefined-management-policies)
- You can also see rich UI
  [image]

[image]